# Make Tornado to listen to Django

Tags: django, tornado

Suppose that I have separate Django and Tornado apps. This is what I want to achieve:
Django receives some POST request and notifies the Tornado app about it so that Tornado app can push notifications to its connected users.
How can I make the Django app to notify a Tornado app? I mean what are the ways of doing this?

P.S.: I'm new to Tornado and async. development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make you Django app GET a url on your Tornado app (i.e. having a REST API on your Tornado app)

Comment: What do you think about making the communication internal using redis? particularly the tornado-redis. I mean the Django publishes to a channel which the Tornado is subscribed to. REST API vs. Redis)

Comment: The REST API is a solution that offers decoupling. I am also wondering if the Redis solution would not add some overhead : Django has to talk to Redis, and then Tornado has to listen to Redis as opposed to Django talks to Tornado.

Comment: Yes, the REST is simpler and straightforward. But in terms of performance and security I guess the redis is a better option, because Tornado won't listen to external requests at all, and will operate like integrated service just pushing messages. Anyway, I think I'll go with REST API since it seems to be more elegant solution) Thanks!